# How to use webpack CLI output a module which can be imported?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack

There are three files here.

file 1: src/module/a/index.js

```
import b from './b.js'; 
import c from '../c/index.js'; 

const d = () => 'd'; 

export default { b, c, d };
```

file 2: src/module/a/b.js

```
export default () => 'b';
```

file 3: src/module/c/index.js

```
export default () => 'c'
```

I want to use the webpack CLI to package the code into a file.

```
// file dist/lib/a.js 
const b = () => 'b'; 
const c = () => 'c'; 
const d = () => 'd'; 

export default { b, c, d };
```

Comment: You are using ES6, you need a transpiler like babeljs to convert your code, I don't think you can do it with just cli. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using ES6 code, you will need transpiler like babel, to do so you need a `webpack.config.js` file in your root directory.

Here is minimal setup for you `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js', // path to your index.js
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js', // output file
    publicPath: 'build/' // output dir
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is your minimal `package.json` file

Add your script, you can run it later via `npm run build` command

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

Add your dev dependencies, you can later install it using `npm install`, or just install it separately using command

`npm i --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env webpack`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
}
```

Depending on your needs you can later add other babel presets, like `es2015` and `stage-0`

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Now add `.babelrc` file into your root directory, paste this code

```
{
"presets": ["babel-preset-env"]
}
```